# css animation with keyframes on chrome isn't playing

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to make a simple animation where a paragraph tag loops around a div. Currently, I can't get the animation to play at all. After some looking, I saw a few other questions on SO where the solution was to add vendor prefixes. I'm on Chrome, so I added that prefix. That didn't work. I saw another where I needed to add the vendor prefix to the animation property, so I tried that. That didn't work, either.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Animations</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="box">
            <p class="animated">Hello</p>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css in css/main.css:

```
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

@keyframes around {
    0% { left: 0;top: 0; }
    25% { left: 500px; top: 0; }
    50% { left: 500px; top: 500px; }
    75% { left: 0; top: 500px; }
    100% { left: 0; top: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes around {
    0% { left: 0;top: 0; }
    25% { left: 500px; top: 0; }
    50% { left: 500px; top: 500px; }
    75% { left: 0; top: 500px; }
    100% { left: 0; top: 0;}
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.animated {
    animation: around 4s ease-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation: around 4s linear infinite;
}
```

I have a codepen of it here: http://codepen.io/khall47/pen/pNogKz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the `left`/`top` property values on an element, it needs to have a position or else nothing happens, so ..

..give the `.animated` rule `position: relative;` and it will work fine.

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLOrwy

*Side note, always put prefixed properties before non-prefixed in your CSS rules*

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your paragraph. It's because it's not declared in relative that it doesn't move. (neither on firefox)

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, if you want to have the same `animation-timing-function` for all the browser, you should give the same for all in `.animated` CSS block.

They both should be either:

```
.animated {
    animation: around 4s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: around 4s linear infinite;
}
```

or

```
.animated {
    animation: around 4s ease-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation: around 4s ease-out infinite;
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily, the OP might want different animation effects on different browser types, so there is nothing wrong in doing what's done

Comment: And in either case, I would have expected to see something happen. Instead I got nothing at all.

Comment: @LGSon yeah, calling this as a mistake might not be proper but most of the time, this kind of things happens while copying and pasting the code samples from somewhere else and you might not realize it since you are testing your code in just one browser.

Comment: Exactly, but now that is fixed :)

Comment: @redeagle47 since I have stated in my answer that my answer was not the solution for your question (solution had been already given). I simply wanted to inform you about a potential future problem.